# How to provide the default logging path by properties file in log4j2?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I'd like to configure my log4j2.xml so that the logging path in controlled by a properties file (so I could switch it during dev or production just by providing a different properties file).

Is there anything similar to the following pseudo code?

```
<Configuration>
    <Properties>
        <property name="path">$loggingPath</property>
    </Properties>
</Configuration>
```

application.properties

```
loggingPath=d:\logging
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the ${sys:system.property.name} syntax.
For more detail see the [Lookups](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html) manual page.

---

UPDATE: Sorry, I did not read your question carefully. Something close to what you are asking for is the bundle format mentioned in the [Property Substitution](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution) section of the Configuration page. This does a lookup in a resource bundle. The format is `${bundle:BundleName:BundleKey}`. The bundle name follows package naming conventions, for example: `${bundle:com.domain.Messages:MyKey}`.